# How to calculate overall average propagation delay for digital circuit given

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, homework, timing-analysis

Using the circuit shown with 3 inputs {A,B,C}, and outputs {F1,F2,F3}, and using the average propagation shown below for each gate:
AND -> tpd = 9ns,
XOR -> tpd = 8ns,
OR -> tpd = 10ns

Calculate the average propagation delay for the below-given circuit.

[image: Circuit]

My approach:
Average propagation delay:
Adding 2 AND gates in series 9+9 = 18ns
Adding 1 AND and 1 XOR in series 9+8 = 17ns
As 18ns is bigger value, we take 18ns and ignore 17ns and add tpd for OR gate
18 + 10 = 28 ns
Is 28 ns the correct answer?

Comment: (Question re-opened after solution attempt was added.)

Comment: That's not strictly the answer to the question - that is the average worst-case prop delay for F2. Not the average prop-delay. The average prop-delay depends upon which path is taken and which output is in question.

Comment: @Kevin Please can you suggest the most probable solution.

Comment: I just think the question is wrongly worded. There are 3 separate outputs. There is a different answer for each. It could be "Calculate the worst-case path delay for each of the outputs from this circuit using the given gate delays" or similar.

Comment: @Kevin White - May be possible. But I have exact wordings of what I got.

Comment: @Sandy - Hi, Is this a multiple-choice question, where you can give us the available options for the answer, and we can try to reverse-engineer what approach the question-setter intended from those options?

Comment: In combinational circuits like this, only two kinds of paths make sense for timing analysis, it's either the path with worst propagation delay (used for setup analysis), or the path with least propagation delay (used for hold analysis), "average propagation delay", whatever it means, doesn't make any useful quantity for timing analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, assuming zero wire delays, the correct answer is 28 ns. It is the critical path aka worst-delay path to the output, which is relevant to the timing analysis of the circuit: \$ A/B \rightarrow AND \rightarrow AND \rightarrow OR \rightarrow F2 \$

Comment: You welcome. Kindly accept an answer once it solves your problem.